# Migrating WSL configuration to another machine

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL set up on two machines, my laptop and my desktop. I spend most of my time on my laptop so that version is configured exactly how I want it. To save me reconfiguring WSL on my desktop (and/or when I reinstall Windows), is there a way of copying the configuration over from my laptop?

Comment: not clear what configuration you mean.  if this is about all dotfiles of your user profile at your laptop then you just need to copy contents of your `%localappdata%\lxss\home\%username%` folder to the desktop

Comment: You may check this answer about [how to backup and restore a WSL distribution](https://superuser.com/a/1344203/756164).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to backup (WSL) Linux Subsystem for Windows 10, before system reset or reinstall?](https://superuser.com/questions/1164818/how-to-backup-wsl-linux-subsystem-for-windows-10-before-system-reset-or-reins)