# How to import a previously exported Ubuntu tarball in WSL?

Tags: ubuntu, tar, windows-subsystem-for-linux, import

My question is continuation of post https://superuser.com/a/1435841

I had installed WSL, installed Ubuntu app from Microsoft Store,
made smth into Ubuntu, 
then I backed it to tar archive by command

> wsl –export Ubuntu C:\Programs\ubuntu.tar

---

Now I'm trying to restore Ubuntu
to the state,  that were backed up into archive.

I'm confusing what steps I should to do?

```
1) Install Ubuntu app from store
2) run "wsl --import -d Ubuntu C:\Programs\ubuntu.tar"
```

or

```
1) run "wsl --import -d Ubuntu C:\Programs\ubuntu.tat"
2) Install back Ubuntu app from Store
```

or
I haven't need to install app from store?

But then i'm losing short way to type "ubuntu" in search
and run ubuntu app

---

UPDATE:
tried to move tar on another PC (Windows 10 Pro v1803),
installed here wsl in powershell, trying to import and...

```
C:\Users\nameless>wsl --import Ubuntu C:\Ubuntu C:\disc\ubuntu.tar
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions. Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store: https://aka.ms/wslstore
```

Okay, in Windows 10 Pro v1903 that has been fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to how I read the documentation, importing a WSL distribution is not
connected at all to the Microsoft Store.

You do the import using the command of:

```
wsl --import <DistributionName> <InstallLocation> <Full path to .tar FileName>
```

From now on WSL knows about `DistributionName`, but the Microsoft Store doesn't.

To execute this distribution you will need the command of:

```
wsl --distribution <DistributionName>
```

This means that just running `ubuntu.exe` (or whatever) will not work,
unless you add it to the PATH environment variable.

You might try to install the distribution from the Microsoft Store, then overwrite
it, using its name (which you can also see using `wsl --list`).
This might work so the imported distribution is both registered in the
Microsoft Store and in the PATH (but I haven't tried it myself).

Comment: "You might try to install the distribution from the Microsoft Store, then overwrite it" - that's not worked well for me, i tried some cycles of doing "wsl --unregister, then wsl --import" in different variations...Huh, seems I have to put up with having "portable Ubuntu" in some folder on my computer.

Comment: I've called command like <DistributionName> = -d, <InstallLocation> = Ubuntu. That was incorrect

Comment: `-d` doesn't exist, the commands are as in my answer.

Comment: `ubuntu.exe` etc. will work if the distribution name is exactly similar with Ubuntu-18.04.